# Reshape and plot 3 quantities with commun Label (geom_text)

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data as follow :

```
k2=structure(list(Hour = c("17:02:00", "17:04:00", "17:07:00", "17:13:00", 
"17:14:00", "17:17:00", "17:19:00", "17:22:00", "17:28:00", "17:29:00"
), Cat1 = c(300L, 304L, 272L, 171L, 271L, 376L, 284L, 177L, 218L, 
284L), Cat2 = c(15L, 45L, 36L, 31L, 36L, 26L, 26L, 32L, 46L, 
32L), Cat3 = c(850L, 1073L, 612L, 537L, 709L, 929L, 870L, 452L, 
474L, 696L), Label = c("BA", "EL", "BA", "CI", "MO", 
"BA", "EL", "BA", "CI", "RO")), .Names = c("Hour", 
"Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Label"), row.names = c("163", "164", 
"165", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "173", "174"), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm stack with a simple question of plot as follow : X will express time, and Y will cumul respectively quantities of `Cat1` , `Cat2` , `Cat3`. For a given time, the three quantities will have the same `Label`.
I reshaped my data as follow, but it is not ok because I have a `geom_text = Label` for each cat while the three have the same `Label`.

```
k2$Hour=format(k2$Hour, format='%H:%M:%S' )
meltk2 = melt(k2, id = c("Hour","Label"))
meltk2$Hour <- as.POSIXct(paste("2012-11-03", meltk2$Hour, "CEST"))

ggplot(meltk2, aes(x=Hour , y = value, group = Hour, colour = variable)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
        scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S")) +   
        geom_text(aes(label = as.character(Label)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), vjust = -0.6)
```

What is the healthiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want only 1 common label visible at each timestamp? Changing `geom_text`'s y value to a number would set all 3 labels to the same location, effectively showing only one:

```
ggplot(meltk2, aes(x=Hour, y = value, group = Hour, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S")) +   
  geom_text(aes(label = as.character(Label)), y=0, vjust = 1)
```

(I set y=0 to position the labels at the bottom. You may want to pick some other height.)

[image: stacked plot]

If you don't want the bars to be stacked (as per PoGibas' answer):

```
ggplot(meltk2, aes(x=Hour, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S")) +   
  geom_text(aes(label = as.character(Label)), y=0, vjust = 1)
```

[image: dodged plot]